# How to display data row wise for every day per week in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table in which userid, clockInTime , clockOutTime and ClockDate are stored like below

```
ID  BId     ClockInDateTime           ClockOutDateTime              ClockDate             UserId
6   1   2013-09-06 03:46:00.000 2013-09-06 05:46:15.000 1   2013-09-06 05:46:46.657      1
7   1   2013-09-06 01:50:19.480 2013-09-06 05:50:26.383 1   2013-09-06 05:50:19.480      2
8   1   2013-09-07 02:08:17.253 2013-09-07 06:08:21.153 1   2013-09-07 06:08:17.253      1
9   1   2013-09-07 03:46:10.300 2013-09-07 07:46:14.827 2   2013-09-07 07:46:10.300      2 
10  1   2013-09-06 03:48:16.807 2013-09-06 07:48:19.967 2   2013-09-06 07:48:16.807      3
```

now i want to display data asw below per user

```
Name        Mon     Tue     Wed         Thus        Fri         Sat         Sun        
N. Patel    8:00:40 9:00:40 10:00:40    11:00:40    12:00:40    13:00:40    14:00:40    
M. Bruell   8:00:40 9:00:40 10:00:40    11:00:40    12:00:40    13:00:40    14:00:40
```

here i want record day wise per user in single row, is there any query without using cursor? from userid i will get username but for every day there are new record for new day, but for week i want that record in single row day wise, and daily working hours for each day by        ClokInDateTime and ClockOutDateTime, and if Shift is between 9:00 P.M to 6:00 A.M  then first 3 hours should be display on that day and other 6 hour should be display in next day,

Comment: Google `Pivot` in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Else show what have you **tried** so far. People will help you

Comment: Thank u very much for your suggestion of PIVOT, i have tried cursor for each date, but its  very long process, i was hope that there should be simple query to do it.. so i asked.. now i am trying with PIVOT.. Thanks a lot..